# Кодировка Python base64 Incorrect Padding

Tags: python, кодировка, base64

У меня есть строка такого вот ужасного вида

UEdoMGJXdytQR2hsWVdRK1BIUnBkR3hsUHRDZjBMN1F2OUdBMEw3UXNkR0QwTG5SZ3RDMUlOQ3YwTDNRdE5DMTBMclJnUzdRbjlDKw0KMFlmUmd0R0RJTkMwMEx2Ump5QkJibVJ5YjJsa0lOQzRJR2xRYUc5dVpUd3ZkR2wwYkdVK1BDOW9aV0ZrUGp4aWIyUjVJSE4wZVd4bA0KUFNKd1lXUmthVzVuT2lBd2NIZzdJRzFoY21kcGJqb2dNSEI0T3lJK0NqeGth...

```
text.decode('base64')
```

Вызывает исключение binascii.Error: Incorrect padding

Пробовал такое:

```
missing_padding = len(text) % 4
if missing_padding != 0:
     text += b'=' * (4 - missing_padding)
text.decode('base64')
```

Итог: тоже самое

Upd:

У меня было две неподходящие строки, теперь одна, вот код:

```
decode_text = decode_text.replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '').replace('\t', '').replace(' ', '').replace('=', '').strip()
missing_padding = len(decode_text) % 4
if decode_text != 0:
    decode_text += b'=' * (4 - missing_padding)
decode_text = base64.b64decode(decode_text)
```

Итог - ошибка в одной строке, другая прошла удачно. Видимо, какой-то еще момент не учли. Строка - письмо с почты. Слишком длинная, чтобы скинуть сюда

Ошибка raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: Incorrect padding

То есть другая уже, но я проверяю, длина строки делится на 4...

Comment: Проверь, что внутри преобразуемого текста нет переводов строк и/или пробелов. Если есть - удали их. А так в принципе нормально декодируется в `<html><head><title> .  Android  iPhone</title></head><body style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">...`

Comment: убрал пробелы, переносы строк, символы / и +. Теперь код без ошибок, но возвращаются каракули типо &R��F��"7G��S�&6���#�3

Comment: Base64 хорошо документирован как бы... набор используемых символов известен (52 буквы, 10 цифр, плюс и слэш). Все иные символы - удалять.

Comment: не убрал плюс и слэш, та же ошибка появляется..

Comment: Всего нужно: 1) убрать все невалидные символы 2) добавить в конец знаки равно `=`, чтобы общая длина нацело делилась на 4. Всё.

Comment: с одной строкой помогло, с другой нет

Comment: Откуда у вас та base64 строка?

Comment: Письмо с почты (imap)